# In android OneSignal push notification app_id not found when the app data is cleared

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

OneSignal push notification works fine, but when the app data is cleared am get
app_id not found warning

```
08-12 18:39:37.001 31263-9731/om.example.onesignalexample D/OneSignal: POST SEND JSON: {"tags":{"test_user":"true","tester_Id":"001"}}
08-12 18:39:37.483 31263-9731/om.example.onesignalexample W/OneSignal: POST RECEIVED JSON: {"errors":["app_id not found."]}
08-12 18:39:37.503 31263-9731/com.example.onesignalexample W/OneSignal: Failed last request. statusCode: 400 response: {"errors":["app_id not found."]}
```

Comment: You are only clearing the cache and not the data? I am not able to reproduce the issue with the latest OneSignal Android 3.0.0 SDK. What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: Sorry just now edited the question when am cleared the app data am getting get app_id not found warning, am using android version 4.4.4 kitkat

Comment: Clearing all data by pressing "CLEAR DATA" from the settings menu should have the same effect as uninstalling the app and reinstalling it. Can  you send the full logcat to OneSignal support? Their should be an entities before these that show the the create player or on_session call.

Comment: The `app_id not found` error was due to a bug in 3.0.0 where extra network calls were made when using sendTags when the device registration would take longer than normal. [Version 3.0.1](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/releases/tag/3.0.1) fixes these extra network calls. The device not registering issue isn't related to this bug or clearing app data. It would be an issue with the device, project, or an issue Android is pausing threads if you background your app before it finishes registering.

Comment: Thanks Now its working fine.